# Enabling and selecting a radio button is not doing the selecting, but only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've a problem wherein a checkbox is set so that checking it will enable and select a radio button that is usually disabled, and unchecking it will disable that same radio (and select another default option).

In Firefox, checking the box will enable the radio as expected, will then trigger the bound event to log "checked_radio click" to the console, but *will not visually change the radio button or set the radio's checked property to true*. The now-enabled radio can be selected as normal afterwards (triggering the click event a second time).

The reverse - unchecking the box correctly disables the radio and selects the default - works as expected.

It all works as intended in both Chrome and Safari, and seems to be failing regardless of which version of jQuery I use. Firefox version 28 and 29 have show then problem, no other versions tried. All attempts on Mac OS X Mavericks.

**So, what's going wrong here?**

---

I've reproduced the problem in a minimal state in a **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Df/1/)**, the code of which is reproduced below as well for completeness.

Expected behaviour:

- When you check the checkbox, the 'checked radio' option should become enabled and selected (the selection here is what is failing for me in Firefox).
- When you uncheck the checkbox the 'unchecked radio' option should be selected, while the 'checked radio' option should become disabled.

The HTML:

```html
<label>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    Control Checkbox
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <input id="checked_radio" name="radios" type="radio" value="on">
</label>
    Checked Radio
<br>
<label>
    <input id="unchecked_radio" name="radios" type="radio" value="off" checked>
    Unchecked Radio
</label>
```

And the accompanying JavaScript:

```js
var checkbox        = null
var checked_radio   = null
var unchecked_radio = null

$(document).ready(function(){
  checkbox        = $('#checkbox')
  checked_radio   = $('#checked_radio')
  unchecked_radio = $('#unchecked_radio')

  checkbox.click(update_radio)

  checked_radio.click(function(){ console.log('checked_radio click') })
  unchecked_radio.click(function(){ console.log('unchecked_radio click') })

  update_radio()
})

function update_radio() {
  if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
    checked_radio.prop('disabled', false)
    checked_radio.click()
  } else {
    unchecked_radio.click()
    checked_radio.prop('disabled', true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `checked_radio.prop('checked', true)` instead of `checked_radio.click()`

Comment: That does work. I was using `click()` as there are bound events that I want to be triggered. Obviously I could do both, but that feels like it should be unnecessary. Any idea why `click()` does not work?

Comment: Well that's the way it works :) Click will fire click event, but not necessary trigger checked state.

Comment: You can call `click()` on the element immediately after checking the checkbox (from the console anyway) and it will work exactly as expected - it just seems to be in tandem with the enabling where isn't not functioning as expected.